# no transition to next page

Tags: android, kotlin

```
`class AmainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_amain)

    val buttonnazz: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonnazz)
    val buttonsreda: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonsreda)
    val buttonpon: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonpon)
    val buttonpyatn: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonpyatn)

    buttonnazz.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, RspActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    buttonsreda.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this, SreActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    buttonpon.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, PonActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    buttonpyatn.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, PyatnActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
}`
```

I have 4 buttons. Each of them makes a transition to a specific page,but only 2 buttons work, the exit button and 1 button that goes to the next page.

I tried changing the names and code. Ultimately I want all 4 buttons to work